# firewalld at Almalinux 9 does not apply other zones when 'sources' is specified and matched

Tags: firewalld

I'm migrating from Almalinux 8 (RedHat 8) to Almalinux 9 (RedHat 9) and have got strange behaviour of **firewalld**.

Here is the condiguration I have (as listed by `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`):

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client
  ports: 443/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

ssh-4-me (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 111.111.0.0/16
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

The purpose is - allow SSH only from the sub-net of trusted hosts. It works just as I expect at Almalinux 8, but at Almalinux 9 it seems that once source fits into `111.111.0.0/16` of zone `ssh-4-me (active)` only rules explicitly specified in that zone are applied - i.e. I can connect to SSH, but I can't connect to 443 allowed via `public` zone. Connection starts working if I explicitly add 443 to zone `ssh-4-me`, but this way supposes I need to copy everything from `public` to `ssh-4-me` and I do not like such approach.

I suppose there is some other 'configuration option' I'm not aware about which prevents applying `public` zone in that case.

How this can be fixed? How can I force firewalld to use the `public` zone even if `source` matches another zone?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well.

It turns out to be a behavioral change: https://firewalld.org/2020/01/allowzonedrifting

Unfortunately, it's not possible to enable AllowZoneDrifting in RHEL 9 and derivatives. I've tested this on AlmaLinux 9 without success, and the Red Hat documentation confirmed that this setting is being ignored.